# Getting Value From Popup Window Using only JS & HTML

Tags: javascript, popup, cross-page-postback

Is it possible to get a value from a popup window? Additionally I would like to use JS and HTML only, i.e. no PHP. Is this even possible? I've seen other posts on here like this one:

[getting value from popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9919857/getting-value-from-popup-window)

but that's in aspx.

I have googled a bit and found this link:

http://www.bignosebird.com/js/popmap.shtml

However, it works on that guys site but not when i copy and paste it, I may be a noob so this is what I have:

**parent.html**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="maparea" SIZE=2 VALUE="">
<input type=button onClick='targetitem = document.forms[0].maparea; dataitem = window.open("map.shtml", "dataitem", "toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes"); dataitem.targetitem = targetitem' value="Show Map">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**map.shtml**

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function select_item(item)
{
targetitem.value=item;
top.close();
return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<CENTER>
<B>Our Map</B>
<BR>

<IMAGE SRC="map1.gif" ISMAP USEMAP="#MAP1">
<MAP NAME="MAP1">
<AREA SHAPE=RECT COORDS="11,10,116,133" HREF="" onClick='return select_item("1")'>
<AREA SHAPE=RECT COORDS="121,11,227,172" HREF="" onClick='return select_item("2")'>
<AREA SHAPE=RECT COORDS="11,140,115,226" HREF="" onClick='return select_item("3")'>
<AREA SHAPE=RECT COORDS="119,177,225,227" HREF="" onClick='return select_item("4")'>
<AREA SHAPE=default HREF="" >
</MAP>
</CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me (using Firefox 20.0). But the code is really ugly and old though, probably you should study the present standards of [MSDN Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) to understand how it works in firefox (Window object may change its behaviour in other browsers). Ah, and of course the [ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) . But to introuduce one of the multiple solutions, you could try this:
**parent.html**

```
<input type="text" id="output"/>
<button id="show">Open</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function(){
        window['output'] = document.getElementById('output');
        window.open('map.html')
    });
</script>
```

**maps.html** (I changed the extension!)

```
<input type="text" id="user_text"/>
<input id="send" type='button' value'send'/>

<script>
    document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function(){
    window.opener['output'].value = document.getElementById('user_text').value;
})
</script>
```

Comment: My fingers are crossed. Gonna give it a try and let u know. BTW I'm using chrome.

Comment: just tried it... it's not working... maybe this is a chrome fault... installing firefox as we speak... connection is a bit slow so i will post back a bit later on.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in firefox. but not in chrome! Thanks Javier for you time and effort.

Comment: AHA! :) Finally figured it out, well thanks to Javier and this site:

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t941764-p2-window-opener-in-chrome.html

**check page 2**

so apprently window.opener will not work in chrome if that html page is access via file:/// I have no idea why, but currently do not care, when I access the file via localhost... it works as desired...